# Is there a Logger naming convention for anonymous classes?

Tags: java

When creating `java.util.logging.Logger` the name parameter is typically the name of the class where it is used. When it is created in an anonymous class how is it typically named? Is there a convention for it?

Comment: If the class is long enough to need a separate logger, it probably shouldn't be anonymous.

Comment: That will probably be "foo.bar.MyClass$1" or something like that

Comment: Or use the parent class' logger.